# how to print a session id afer login the User using laravel

Tags: laravel

I am beginner in Laravel I want to try to print a session of login_id after login the user 
how is it possible to print the login_id related to username after login the user

Pass that login_id into last page

**this is my Controller :**

```
$username = Input::get('username');
$password = Input::get('password');
$rules = array('username' => 'required', 'password' => 'required');
$messages = array('username.required' => 'Username is required', 'password.required' => 'Password is required');
$validate = Validator::make($input, $rules, $messages);
Session::put('username', Input::get('username'));
Session::get('username');
if (Session::has('username')) {
    $data = Session::get('username');
    //$user_data = DB::logincheck();
    //Session::put('login_id', $user_data->login_id);
}
if ($validate->passes()) {
    $result = DB::table('registration')->where('username', '=', $username)->where('password', '=', $password)->get();
    //$result=DB::table('student')->where('id','2')->where('name',"like",'d%')->get();
    //$res=DB::table('registration')->lastInsertid('reg_id');
    if ($result) {
        $reg_id = Input::get('id');
        $result1 = DB::table('registration')->find('id', $reg_id)->where('data', $username)->get();
        var_dump($result1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Rajesh is there a reason your not making use of the `Auth` fascade? With that you can just do `Auth::id();`.

Comment: Is their any possible without using Auth to create a session using Querybuilder